# How to rebuild only a spesific item in the Listview?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have an entity object, for simplicity lets call it now `Todo`. I want to have a widget where I can edit multiple of these todos simultaneously, something like `EditableTodoList` (and this would show a list of `EditableTodo`s).
This widget would recieve a `List<Todo>` and also something like `Function onTodoEdited(Todo)`.
I am trying to use immutable data, so when an `EditableTodo` is being edited (and the event gets propagated to the widget which holds the `EditableTodoList`), I'd create a new `List<Todo>` which contais the updated `Todo`, but then `EditableTodoList` would rebuild with all its `EditableTodo`s inside.

How could I optimize this, that only the relevant `EditableTodo` is rebuilt? I don't want to hack around with mutating the prop original `List<Todo>` because that hides greatly an important detail.

Background: currently the state is inside a cubit and I am `context.select`-ing for every `EditableTodo` list item the corresponding `Todo` in the state, this way only the edited item rebuilds. I'd like to decouple this `EditableTodoList` from the cubit.

Theoretically I assume its not possible, as `EditableTodoList` is given new properties, so it has to rebuild, and that means all subtree gets rebuilt. `EditableTodo` cannot be `const` as its prop is not a constant.
But still, what would be the most elegant way of separating `EditableTodoList` from the cubit? As it only needs a `List<Todo>` to show, it should be possible somehow to optimize the rendering of not changed `Todo`s

Answer (score 2):

You should consider how widget, element and render trees work in order to be concerned. There is a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs) about Flutter's rendering mechanism. When rebuilding a tree, framework [compares](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/canUpdate.html) the two versions of widgets by using only the [key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html) and runtime type values. This means that if you change string value of the `Text` widget, the same render object with mutated data will be used again. New render object won't be created, which means no unnecessary rebuilds will happen on the render tree. Rebuilding the widget tree is not expensive compared to the render tree.

There is a limit on minimizing the the build scope in the `ListView`. `ListView` itself should be rebuilt in order to update an item. So you can't target a spesific item to rebuild. But items can reactively rebuild themselves (eg. an item that listens to a stream can rebuild without effecting the others). Therefore immutable collections doesn't matter in this context since the framework doesn't care the value but key and runtime type. You can either pass a completely modified list or a list with just one element changed, it will have the same effect.

Comment: I see, but then does this mean, that as long as new render objects are not made, all "rebuilds" (call to build methods) are fine? I don't know how much should I thrive for as less rebuilds as possible.
[this article](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app./#avoid-rebuilding-all-the-widgets-repetitively) suggests optimizing the widget tree to minimize the rebuilt subtree

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep trying to minimize the rebuild scope as much as I can